# How to reduce the time delay for loading the large datasource in the CheckedListBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, performance, checkedlistbox

When I set the DataSource of the CheckedListBox with 10lack items. It applecation remains ideal for upto 3 minutes.

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
worker.DoWork += ((o, a) =>
{             
    //1Lakh unique records.
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        list.Add("Item" + i);
});
worker.RunWorkerCompleted += ((obj, ea) =>
{
    //Assign the 1Lack records to the CheckedListBox.

    //>>Here is the UI gets hanged.(Need to wait more than 10 - 20 seconds to gets the response)
    checkedListBox1.DataSource = list;                
});
worker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Is there any way to optimize the time delay for loading the items in th checked list box.

Comment: is it the only one line of code in foreach loop or you have some other code too? why you need 10lac items in the ui at first place? cant you use pagination?

Comment: You want that someone searches your one million items and check some? You should consider to use a different control or filter the datasource before you diplay items.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya i have using this line only for loading the items.

Comment: Why you are loading 1 Million items in the listbox? Can you explain what feature you are trying to implement?

Comment: Use `BeginUpdate` / `EndUpdate` methods.

Comment: I have implemnting the filtering support for my custom control like the Excel. While testing the implementation it's failed to load the large data.

Comment: You can not reduce the time to load items in the CheckListBox. You can avoid freezing the UI by running this loop in background. Another thing you can do is lazy loading. That means you load CheckListBox with a few items in the start and load more items page by page when user scrolls thru it  same as contents are being loaded on facebook when you scroll thru it.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya, I have performed this operation on the `backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted` method is there i am doing any thing wrong? how can i achieve the lazy loading in checked listbox. I think this is what i needed.

Comment: Could you please share the example for using the lazy loading to the control.

Comment: Is there any other way to reduce the loading time on the UI thread? I have used the following way to get the unique items from the datasource and applied the items to the checked listbox.

Answer (score 1):

List, Dictionary and other dynamically expanding collections can greatly benefit from having a pre-defined size. If you know you will put ~ 1 million items in it, set the size to 1 million in the List-constructor. Or use an array if you have a fixed size. But the real problem you are facing is probably the slow GUI update. I'm not familiar with the CheckedListBox-control but if it does support virtualization you should enable that. But I assume it doesn't. Another approach, as suggested in the comments, would be to populate the control in smaller batches and allow the GUI to update in between. Instead of setting the DataSource in one go, try to add them in batches of roughly 100 items while in the DoWork. You probably have to invoke that on the main thread. You could also try and do all this on the main thread right up and use DoEvents in between the batches and see if that does it. Might not be as good as the async method but it's worth a shot.